# Not able to implement ResNet 101 model

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, conv-neural-network, resnet

I am trying to implement ResNet 101 for video classification by following the code from https://gist.github.com/flyyufelix/65018873f8cb2bbe95f429c474aa1294

Tf version - 1.14.0

Input size  -  256 frames X 80 X 60 X 1

[image: Getting this error]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

keras.layers.merge is actually a module and not a function, so you cannot call it. In the architecture of the resnet, you should replace this line with the following:

```
keras.layers.merge.Add([x, shortcut])
```